# Exchange 2010 Error

Tags: exchange-2010

I have been running Exchange 2010 for a little while now and it has been great. Out of the blue I had a user getting failed emails, below if the message. The mailbox could be accessed, but no mail in or out. This has since happened in two additional mailboxes, but it seems intermittent. I have had ZERO luck in finding a root cause for this. Any help is appreciated.

> user@domain.com
>   #550 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Deliver: The Microsoft Exchange Information Store
>   service reported an error. The
>   following information should help
>   identify the cause of this error:
>   "MapiExceptionJetErrorReadVerifyFailure:...,
>   255.23226:0F010480, 255.27962:0E000000, 255.31418:0F010480, 16.18969:82010000, 17.27161:0000000028000000000000000000000000000000,
>   255.23226:0F010480, 255.27962:0E000000, 255.31418:17010480, 16.18969:5E010000, 17.27161:0000000028000000000000000F00000000000000,
>   255.23226:2D000000, 255.27962:0E000000, 255.31418:13800000, 16.18969:1C020000, 17.27161:000000004A020000000000002E00000000000000,
>   255.23226:2D000000, 255.27962:0E000000, 255.27962:0A000000, 255.27962:9E000000, 255.17082:06FCFFFF, 0.18273:00000000, 4.21921:06FCFFFF, 255.27962:FA000000, 255.1494:0E000000, 255.1238:38010000, 4.10484:0F010480, 6.14164:1DFAFFFF030002590F010480, 6.8660:0F0104800300025903001100, 0.18658:0F010480, 6.11956:0F01048003000259B0840110, 4.10484:0F010480, 6.14164:1DFAFFFF0B0002000300DD3F, 6.8660:0F0104800B0002000F010480, 0.18658:40001900, 6.11956:0F0104800B0002000F010480, 4.10484:0F010480, 4.13236:06FCFFFF, 4.6993:06FCFFFF, 4.5041:06FCFFFF, 4.4465:06FCFFFF, 4.6833:06FCFFFF, 0.50217:0F010480, 4.5093:06FCFFFF, 4.5318:06FCFFFF, 4.10104:06FCFFFF, 0.57449:0F010480, 4.6025:05000780, 4.5257:05000780, 4.4606:06FCFFFF, 255.1750:00000000, 0.26849:00000000, 255.21817:06FCFFFF". ##

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message should read: "The following information should help **Microsoft** identify the cause of this error.  I don't think it's going to mean a whole lot to anyone else. =)

That being said, I'm guessing there is something corrupt or corrupting the exchange mailbox database.  I would suggest creating a new mailbox database (on a different drive if possible) and move the affected mailboxes to the new database.  If this solves the problem, you'll know what you have to do.

Comment: That is my weekend already, for a different reason, however I would like to get to the root cause of the corruption as nothing has changed on the server.

Comment: Well, my suggestion is to verify that it is corruption, which is what the new database accomplishes.  Beyond that, the obvious answer to the cause of the corruption is disk failure.

Answer (score 1):

If migration to a new message store is not completing, then you might consider running edbutil to attempt repairing the data store (and then migrating) - after ensuring you have a good backup first.

As for possible causes for the corruption, you might take a look at possible power/application events or hardware issues (e.g. controller caches, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

A post on experts-exchange reveals that someone with a very identical error indeed suffering from a badly corrupted database. These are the steps he took to resolve it.

1) moved that mailbox to a different storage group and a new database
2) Ran eseutil /p then eseutil /d Mounted, Dismounted, ISINTEG -s all tests

You may want to give it a try!

EDIT: If you have an Experts-Exchange account, you can see the thread here:
http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Server_Software/Email_Servers/Exchange/Q_24926844.html